# How do I create a smooth transition in my menu dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I'm trying to figure out how to make a smooth transition in my menu transition. I already wrote a function for the times to appear and disappear onclick, but I'm not sure how to style the transition.

Here's what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<nav id="menu">
  <h2>Menu</h2>
    <ul>
      <li id="toggleTitle">Projects <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
      <li class="projects projectsClass"><a href="#">Project 1</a></li>
      <li class="projects projectsClass"><a href="#">Project 2</a></li>
      <li class="projects projectsClass"><a href="#">Project 3</a></li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

JS:

```
//toggleProjects
var toggleProjects = function(){

//function
var projectsList=document.getElementsByClassName('projects');
// if(projectsList[0].style.display=='none'){
if(!projectsList[0].classList.contains('projectsClass')){
//reappear
for(var i=0; i<projectsList.length; i++){
  // projectsList[i].style.display='';
  projectsList[i].classList.add('projectsClass');
}

} else {
//disappear
for(var i=0; i<projectsList.length; i++){
  // projectsList[i].style.display='none';
  projectsList[i].classList.remove('projectsClass');
}
}
};

//event listener for click
document.getElementById('toggleTitle').addEventListener('click', 
toggleProjects);
```

CSS:

```
.projectsClass {
    display: none;
}

.projects {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

#menu > .toggleTitle {
    padding: 1em 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
}
```

jsfiddlelink:https://jsfiddle.net/j2fygbzb/

Comment: are you using bootstrap? what libraries you're using on this?

Comment: what type of transition you're expecting? drop down or faded visibility or anything new?

Comment: [Check](https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/gsFch) this or [THIS](https://jsfiddle.net/Cerebrl/uhykY/)

Comment: Like @Saharsh said, what do you mean exactly by "smooth transition"?

Comment: @threeFatCat I have jQuery and Skeleton on my website template

Comment: @Saharsh I would optimally like a smooth scroll down, but I don't know how to implement that kind of transition with the code set up I have now (I'm a JS noob).

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t763P/

Comment: it seems on my end your fiddle is not working properly, perhaps because of my proxy or it's just how your fiddle was constructed. All I can see is a `bullet` list and an your even click working.

Comment: that is in "smooth transition" because of jquery `slideToggle` function

Comment: @CourtneyBaker I can see you're using jQuery, this must make your task easier. You may have to rewrite the javascript since if you implement jQuery you won't be needing some already written JS DOM code. As @threeFatCat suggested jQuery's `slideToggle` might be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to do something similar to what you're expecting (or so i think) using your code and only some very slight css modifications. I added a transition css property to `.projects` here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/j2fygbzb/9/

Here's the CSS i changed:

```
.projectsClass {
    max-height: 0 !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}

.projects {
    margin-left: 30px;
    max-height: 20px;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```